# How to give exact type-information in return type without using "any" for a function that returns multiple different types?

Tags: typescript

In my typescript-code I have a function that returns a component based on the navigation-type that has been set by the user, so I can display the component to the user. At the moment the function returns "any" and I am wondering on how to give it exact return types?

I have tried to set multiple types like `Type1 | Type2`, but it does not work and shows errors.

```
  private createEditContainer(entry: any) {
    const component = this.getListComponentByNavType();
    this.editContainer.clear();
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
    this.editComponentRef = this.editContainer.createComponent(factory);
    this.editComponentRef.instance.entry = entry;
  }

  private getListComponentByNavType(): any {   // I want this "any" to be actual types
    switch (this.navtype) {
      case TaskdefinitionNavTypes.TYPE:
        return TaskdefinitionListComponent;
      case TaskdefinitionNavTypes.ENUMS:
        return SingleSelectListComponent;
    }
  }
```

I want to return actual types and not `any`. Or maybe an explanation on why `any` is fine here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this instance you have to use `Type<T>`, this will change your function typing to:

```
private getListComponentByNavType(): Type<TaskdefinitionListComponent | SingleSelectListComponent> {}
```

The component factory resolver will like that better :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the types for the return type in the declaration file or check if the package came with its own type.

Then you can now modify your function to look like this.

```
 private getListComponentByNavType(): TaskdefinitionListComponent | SingleSelectListComponent {  
switch (this.navtype) {
  case TaskdefinitionNavTypes.TYPE:
    return TaskdefinitionListComponent;
  case TaskdefinitionNavTypes.ENUMS:
    return SingleSelectListComponent;
}
```

This should solve your problem.
  }

Comment: That's what I tried already, but it didn't work. See the accepted answer, as I understand it was based on the implementation of the component factory resolver, which is Angular specific. Thanks anyways!